# No carga bien el estilo en Laravel en https

Tags: html, https

Estoy teniendo un problema un poco raro: cuando abro mi dominio normal sin https abre todo bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo abro con https es como si no me cargara el estilo del todo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué podrá ser? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código? Esto puede ocurrir porque los estilos se están incluyendo con http, entonces al cargar la página con https, esos estilos se bloquean porque son inseguros y por eso verías la página sin estilos y mal. Por favor comparte la parte relevante del código para que podamos confirmar si ese es el motivo o no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solucionado, se cambio asset('/css/blabla.css') por secure_asset

asset()
La función de asset() genera una URL para un asset usando el esquema actual de la solicitud (HTTP o HTTPS):

```
$url = asset('img/photo.jpg');
```

secure_asset()
La funcion secure_asset genera una URL para un asset usando HTTPS:

```
 $url = secure_asset('img/photo.jpg');
```